# What does it means that the partial response writer is not integrated with PPRResponseWriter?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to develop an application using JSF, primefaces, Tomcat7.
When I execute an ajax event, I get this warning:

```
17-ott-2012 9.26.04 org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.context.PartialViewContextImpl getPartialResponseWriter
AVVERTENZA: getPartialResponseWriter() called during render_reponse. The returned writer is not integrated with PPRResponseWriter
```

What does it means? What do I have to do to integrate it?
In my server log, on startup, I find some messages about some web context parameters not found. May it be related to the previous warning?
Thanks for your help!!

Comment: This is not specific to PrimeFaces. This is specific to Trinidad. Apparently you're mixing PrimeFaces with Trinidad and this has failed.

Comment: I removed Trinidad libraries from my Build path and it worked!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nice. I reposted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This class is specific to [MyFaces Trinidad](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad). Apparently you're mixing Trinidad with PrimeFaces and it's not working very well. Since you didn't mention anything about Trinidad in your question, it's perhaps a leftover of previous experiments to play around with several component libraries. You might want to remove it before using PrimeFaces.